# What's wrong with my implementation of 2 Factor Authorization?

Tags: php, authorization, sha1, one-time-password, google-authenticator

I'm trying to implement my own PHP function to generate codes for Google Authenticator. I do it for fun and to learn something new. Here's what I did:

```
function twoFactorAuthorizationCode(string $secretBase32, int $digitsCount): string {
    $counter = (int) (time() / 30);
    $secret = Base32::decode($secretBase32);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $counter, $secret, true); // 20 binary characters
    $hexHash = unpack('H*', $hash)[1]; // 40 hex characters
    $offset = hexdec($hexHash[-1]); // last 4 bits of $hash
    $truncatedHash = hexdec(substr($hexHash, $offset * 2, 8)) & 0x7fffffff; // last 31 bits
    $code = $truncatedHash % (10 ** $digitsCount);

    return str_pad($code, $digitsCount, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

I'm not sure which step is wrong, but it doesn't generate the same results as Google Authenticator. Obviously, I tried to play with time offsets in case my clock is not in sync with Google Authenticator's.

Some of the things I'm not sure are:

- Should the secret be decoded from Base32, or should it stay the Base32 string?
- Is the counter a value or a key for SHA1 hash?

I did a lot of experiments and I can't get my algorithm to generate a valid result. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use [spomky-labs/otphp](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp) instead of trying to write it yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky I finally learned what was wrong. If you are interested, please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer by trials and errors. So, the problem was in the `$counter` value that I've been hashing directly:

```
$hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $counter, $secret, true);
```

Instead, it should be a 64-bit binary string made from the `$counter`:

```
$packedCounter = pack('J', $counter);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $packedCounter, $secret, true);
```

## Explanation

Let's say our Unix timestamp is `1578977176`.

That makes the counter as follows: `(int) (1578977176 / 30) = 52632572`.

The value used for hashing needs to be a 64-bit, big endian byte order string. It means that we need to left-pad it with zeros to make it 64-bit.

`52632572` is `11001000110001101111111100` in binary. That's just 26 bits, so we need 38 more. What we have now is:

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000011001000110001101111100010`.

Every character is one byte, so we split it into the groups of 8:

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011 00100011 00011011 11100010`

We can now convert every group to a character by its code:

```
$packedCounter = chr(0b00000000)
               . chr(0b00000000)
               . chr(0b00000000)
               . chr(0b00000000)
               . chr(0b00000011)
               . chr(0b00100011)
               . chr(0b00011011)
               . chr(0b11100010);
```

And that's the string we want to hash, which is exactly what `pack('J', $string)` does.

Voilà!